# example of inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mcu

I'm writing a C program that takes advantage of what is inline assembly.

How do I pass the address of a variable directly to a register?

```
int main(void){
    int pos0=0;
    asm(
        "ldr r4, =registro_pos0\n"
        "add r4, #5\n"
        "str r4, =registro_pos0\n"
    );
}
```

instead of register_pos0 I would like to insert the value of register pos0

Comment: Please add the tag for the architecture you are using; is this ARM?

Comment: Also note that since your code overwrites `r4` it must be declared as a clobber.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes my architecture is arm